# Why do the SByte and Int32 CompareTo() methods behave differently?

Tags: c#, .net

If you run the following code:

```
SByte w = -5;
Console.WriteLine(w.CompareTo(0));

Int32 x = -5;
Console.WriteLine(x.CompareTo(0));

SByte y = 5;
Console.WriteLine(y.CompareTo(0));

Int32 z = 5;
Console.WriteLine(z.CompareTo(0));
```

then you get the following output:

```
-5
-1
5
1
```

Why do these methods with the same name that have almost identical descriptions in the MSDN documentation behave so differently?

Comment: In what way are they behaving differently? It's only the sign of the result that matters. -5 and -1 have the same sign, and 5 and 1 have the same sign. In other words, as far as the documented behaviour is concerned, they're behaving equivalently.

Comment: `SByte - SByte` can not overflow `Int32`, but `Int32 - Int32` can.

Comment: The `IComparable` interface is defined as having to return a value > 0, 0 or < 0. It does not specify which values these have to be exactly. Most people use `1`, `0` and `-1` but any other value is perfectly allowed as well. The only thing that matters are the signs for > and < and 0 for equal.

Comment: `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>` are used for ordering, so it's only important to know whether two objects are equal(zero), one is less- or greater than zero. What value is returned depends on the implementation and is irrelevant.

Answer (score 12):

Because the [`SByte.CompareTo()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/sbyte.cs,62) is implemented like

```
return m_value - value;
```

so a simple subtraction. This works because the `m_value` is converted automatically to `int`, and any possibile combination of values is "legal" with `int`.

With two [`Int32`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,64) this can't be done, because for example `Int32.MinValue.CompareTo(Int32.MaxValue)` would become `Int32.MinValue - Int32.MaxValue` that would be outside the `int` range, and in fact it is implemented as two comparisons:

```
if (m_value < value) return -1;
if (m_value > value) return 1;
return 0;
```

**in general**

The only important "thing" of the returned value of a `CompareTo` is its sign (or if it is 0). The "value" is irrelevant. The return value of 1, 5, 500, 5000, 5000000 of `CompareTo()` are the same. `CompareTo` can't be used to measure "distance" between numbers. So both implementations are equivalent.

It is **totally** wrong to do:

```
if (someValue.CompareTo(someOtherValue) == -1)
```

you must always

```
if (someValue.CompareTo(someOtherValue) < 0)
```

**why the `SByte.CompareTo` is built that way**

`SByte.CompareTo` is implementing a "branchless" comparison (there are no `if`s in the code, the flow of code is linear). Processors have problems with branches, so branchless code *could* be faster than "branchful" code, so this microoptimization. Clearly `SByte.CompareTo` could have been written as `Int32.CompareTo`.

**why any negative value is equivalent to -1 (and any positive value is equivalent to +1)**

This is probably something that is derived directly from the C language: the [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) function for example to compare items uses a user-defined method that is like:

> Pointer to a function that compares two elements.
>   This function is called repeatedly by qsort to compare two elements. It shall follow the following prototype:
>
> int compar (const void* p1, const void* p2);
>
> Taking two pointers as arguments (both converted to const void*). The function defines the order of the elements by returning (in a stable and transitive manner):
>   return value  meaning
>   <0    The element pointed to by p1 goes before the element pointed to by p2
>   0 The element pointed to by p1 is equivalent to the element pointed to by p2
>   >0   The element pointed to by p1 goes after the element pointed to by p2

**how is the `.CompareTo` implemented in other primitive types?**

[`SByte`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/sbyte.cs,61), [`Byte`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/byte.cs,67), [`Int16`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int16.cs,61), [`UInt16`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/uint16.cs,58), [`Char`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs,144) all use the subtraction "method", while [`Int32`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,64), [`UInt32`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/uint32.cs,65), [`Int64`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int64.cs,63), [`UInt64`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/uint64.cs,62) all use the `if` "method".

Comment: You mean CompareTo, not GetHashCode.

Comment: That's the implementation. But does it matter at all? Isn't the real question _why_ `CompareTo` can return other values than `0`, `-1` and `1`. OP doesn't seem to know for what it's normally used: ordering.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are right... I've added some annotations... I hadn't written them because I'm not an expert in CS, so I'm not sure if what I've written is history or more hearsay

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the source for these two methods, they are implemented differently:

```
public int CompareTo(sbyte value)
{
    return (int)(this - value);
}
```

vs

```
public int CompareTo(int value)
{
    if (this < value)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (this > value)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

But none of this matters, since the sign of the returned value is the only thing that you should be checking.